# html parsing with php simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, parsing, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm parsing internet newspapers's columinst page. I have problem about this site

> http://www.sozcu.com.tr/kategori/yazarlar/

the parsing was working fine in the starting but it stopped working.

Here's my code

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$gazeteAdress);
//curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'mozilla');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($query);
```

I don't know why my code sometimes is not parsing the site, so I was thinking about connection_timeout. But It is not the problem, so I was thinking of printing html page with curl instead.

```
echo $html;
```

Here is result. (sometimes my code is not parsing html page properly)
[image]

why the html tags are not coming and why am seeing the result like this. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is returned compressed so you should specify Accept-Encoding with 'gzip,deflate' header for curl.

Please add this line
`curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");`
after this
`curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'mozilla');`

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of your php script

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: have this: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/HTML; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: You don't need this, only <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: mate sometimes it is work but sometimes it is not.. It is not the Turkish character problem